# Selecting a Number No More Than Twice

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to have a batch file assign a random number to a list of 99 variables. However, I do not want the same number assigned more than twice. The code below does not seem to work, and it is throwing a `Divide by zero error` at me. I have tinkered around with it and looked for help online but could not find any.

My code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a var=99
for /l %%i in (1,1,50) do set "count_%%i=0"
for /l %%i in (1,1,%var%) do call :assign %%i
:assign
set /a rand=!random! %%50 +1
if !count_%%rand%%! lss 2 (
    set /a var%1=!rand!
    set /a "count_%%rand%%+=1"
    goto :eof
) else goto food
for /l %%i in (1,1,%var%) do echo !var%%i!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
for /l %%e in (0,1,99) do SET "var%%e="
for /l %%e in (0,1,99) do CALL :assign %%e
for /l %%e in (1,1,99) do CALL echo var%%e=%%var%%e%%
ECHO -------------------
SET var
GOTO :eof

:assign
set /a rand=%random% %% 100
if DEFINED var%rand% GOTO assign
SET /a var%rand%=1+%1/2
GOTO :EOF
```

Just a small change in approach.

For the numbers 0..99, execute the `assign` subroutine.

`:assign` selects a random number 0..99, and repeats that selection until it finds a VAR?? that's not been assigned. It assigns `1+%1/2` to VAR??

Since `%1` will have the value 0..99, the number assigned will be 1,1,2,2..50,50 to a random `var` variable.

Then two separate ways of showing the result. `var0` can simply be disregarded.

Your approach simply won't work because a `code block` (parenthesised sequence of commands) cannot contain a label as labels terminate the block.

Comment: I have edited my post and I have added a label for assigning the random numbers. Your code would not work for me because I need to assign other variables to fill in the gaps (in this case, one spot left). All 50 variables are split in 2, which allows the 99 separate variables to be split among them. I just dont want the same number being chosen twice.

Comment: I really cannot understand what you've said. Since there are 50 numbers, none chosen more than twice to be assigned to 99 variables, each must be assigned twice with one assigned only once. The one that is assigned once will be at var0. What "other variables" are involved? What gaps? There are 99 variables assigned. What do you mean by the 99 variables to be split among them? Now an example of what you mean would be useful. Doesn't need to be 50/99. 4/8 will probably suffice.

Comment: Sorry, sorry. I did not give the full details. Lets say I want 2 types of variables, `a`, and `b`. `a` will have an amount of 99 and `b` will have an amount of 1. I want `a` and `b` to be assigned randomly generated numbers (1-50). However, I want the numbers that get generated only be picked no more than twice each. `b` would take up 99 slots, and `a` would take up 1. I am doing this for a simulation.

Comment: Your code only works for one set of variables, and I need a second one to fill in the remaining slots left over.

Comment: The variables `var`..`var99` will contain a random number 1..50; Any particular number assigned will occur twice, except for one that will only occur once (since 99 slots, 50 numbers). The variable `var0` will contain the number 1..50 that only occurs once in `var1`..`var99`

Comment: My program makes it so that you could customize the amount for each variable. Having 1 leftover is not going to work, because if I had, lets say, 30 `a` and 70 `b`, then it would not work and I would have to modify the code. The problem that I am having is that when I run my code, it says `Divide by zero error.` Could you please explain why, and a possible solution? I already removed the code block and replaced it with a label, yet I am still getting the same error.